# how to get nth element from List in f# using option

Tags: list, functional-programming, f#

Im new to f# and i'm trying to make this exercise:
"Implement a function"

```
let rec nth(n : int) (l : List<'a>) : Option<'a> =
```

that returns the element in position n in l. The function must handle appropriately the case where the index is invalid

this is my current code but I'm kinda stuck:

```
let rec nth (n : int) (l : List<'a>) : Option<'a> =
    if n > l.Length then
        None
    else
        match l with
        | [] -> None
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm also a beginner, but can't you use `Some l.[index]` in the else path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use any functionality provided by the core library at all? If so, I suggest the following function:

```
let nth (n : int) (l : 'a list) : 'a option =
    if n < 1 || n > l.Length then None else Some l.[n - 1]
```

This just checks whether the index is within permitted boundaries, then returns the element at the appropriate index. The index-item operator is zero-based, therefore we need to subtract one from the number passed into the function, and the list iteration is done by the compiler behind the scenes.

If you need to do it completely manually, I suggest the following function:

```
let nth (n : int) (l : 'a list) : 'a option =
    let rec inner i = function
        | [] -> None
        | x :: _ when i = 0 -> Some x
        | _ :: xs -> inner (i - 1) xs
    if n < 1 then None else inner (n - 1) l
```

This checks the lower boundary, and if it is all right, starts to iterate the list using an inner function, and decrementing the index until it is zero so it knows it reached the right index. If the list is shorter, `None` is returned.

Comment: There's already a Core function, `List.tryItem` that does this. Btw, you probably want this zero-based, as all other functions in F# usually are.

Comment: it seems to work thanks! though I think i'm supposed to do it with pattern matching even though it is not specified in the exercise. :')
something with ```match l with```

Comment: You can rewrite the inner function as follows: ``let rec inner i l = match l with | …`` It produces exactly the same code. In other words, ``function`` allows you to omit the last parameter, and match on it implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in function List.tryItem

```ml
let rec nth(n : int) (l : List<'a>) : Option<'a> =
    l |> List.tryItem n
```

Comment: Yes, tryItem is for sure the easiest solution

Comment: Welcome to SO, Esté.

Comment: unfortunately i'm supposed to build my own without using the f# built-in functions TT